# javascript time browser issue

Tags: javascript, browser

We have a problem with different browsers.
In Chrome everything works fine, but in firefox the code doesnt work.

Its this code:

```
            currentTime = new Date();
            var jaar = currentTime.getFullYear();
            var maand = ('0' + (currentTime.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
            var dag = currentTime.getDay();
            var uur = currentTime.getHours();
            var minuut = currentTime.getMinutes();
            var seconden = currentTime.getSeconds();
            var huidigetijd = (jaar + '-' + maand + '-' + dag + ' ' + uur + ':' + minuut + ':' + seconden);
            var gpsdatum = tijd;
            var gpstime = new Date();
            var gpsjaar = new Date(gpsdatum).getFullYear();
            var gpsmaand = ('0' + (gpstime.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
            var gpsdag = new Date(gpsdatum).getDay();
            var gpsuur = new Date(gpsdatum).getHours() + 1;
            var gpsminuut = new Date(gpsdatum).getMinutes();
            var gpsseconden = new Date(gpsdatum).getSeconds();
            var gps = (gpsjaar + '-' + gpsmaand + '-' + gpsdag + ' ' + gpsuur + ':' + gpsminuut + ':' + gpsseconden);

                    if (gps >= huidigetijd){
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map : map,
                        position : point,
                        icon : chasericoon,
                        html : html
                        }); // einde var marker
                    markersArray.push(marker);
                    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
                    };//einde gps timeout
```

I've tried something with " and ' but that doesnt make any sense.
Can someone help me with this ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getDay()` returns the day of the week (0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday...)

You want `getDate()` instead, and you will need to use the `"0"+....slice(-2)` trick to ensure it is zero-padded too. And the same padding trick on the hours, minutes and seconds too.